# How to flush left one row in align

Tags: align

How to flush left the first short row in this align?

[image: flush left first row]

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{\textbf{Year 1:}}\\ \$1000 + 0.05(\$1000)& = \$1000(1 + 0.05)\\
& = \$1000(1.05)\\
& = \$1050
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you want no overlap at all, then you could simply add two `&&` before the second (and later) line(s).  another possibility might be to apply the `multline` environment with an embedded `aligned` sub-environment.

Comment: Just edit my question to add real sense!!

Comment: Editing your question that way would change the question, potentially making answers inappropriate.

Comment: The revised example still doesn't need alignment as all the lines have the same length, your test file would make the intent clearer and a lot easier to test example if you used different text in each row. (@barbarabeeton)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}

\noindent\textbf{Year 1:}
\begin{align*}
\$1000 + 0.05(\$1000)& = \$1000(1 + 0.05)\\
& = \$1000(1.05)\\
& = \$1050
\end{align*}

\bigskip

\begin{align*}
\intertext{\textbf{Year 1:}}
\$1000 + 0.05(\$1000)& = \$1000(1 + 0.05)\\
& = \$1000(1.05)\\
& = \$1050
\end{align*}

}

\end{document}
```

(new answer after question updated)

Comment: Although `align` may seem strange, when I commented on the question, I made the assumption that the lines after the first would not all be the same length, but would contain an `=` sign where alignment would make sense.  It would be helpful if you could expand your answer to include this assumption.